# Generate a 2 week view with Codeigniter's Calendar library from current week

Tags: php, codeigniter, calendar

I'm trying to make a 2 week view with Codeigniter's calendar library, basically I don't need a full month view, instead I'd like to have a 2 week view from the current week.

[image]

The image above shows similarity what I want to achieve. On the templating side of Codeigniter when generating does not offer this kind of feature. I do not want to use jQuery UI's calendar due to I need a static calendar instead of relying on JS to perform this (especially when users have disabled JS).

Is there a specific extended library I can merge with Codeigniter's or a specific template string that can perform this type of calendar view?

Comment: fyi, regarding the 'js disabled' concern: http://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydn/posts/2010/10/how-many-users-have-javascript-disabled/

Answer (score 1):

You have to extend the calendar library for this.

In `application/libraries` create a `MY_Calendar.php`:

```
class MY_Calendar extends CI_Calendar {
    public function generate2weeks($year = '', $month = '', $data = array())
    {
        // code goes here
    }
}
```

Have look at the [CI_Calendar::generate()](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/libraries/Calendar.php) function. You have to write a new function `generate2weeks()` where you basically do the same as in `generate()` but with less days. I would make a copy of `generate()` and work from here. Maybe it would be enough to overwrite `get_total_days` worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

You need to extend the Calendar class and override the `generate()` method. I've spent a little bit of time to tweak the `generate()` function and this is what I got.

```
function generate($year = '', $month = '', $data = array())
{
    // Set and validate the supplied month/year
    if ($year == '')
        $year  = date("Y", $this->local_time);

    if ($month == '')
        $month = date("m", $this->local_time);

    if (strlen($year) == 1)
        $year = '200'.$year;

    if (strlen($year) == 2)
        $year = '20'.$year;

    if (strlen($month) == 1)
        $month = '0'.$month;

    $adjusted_date = $this->adjust_date($month, $year);

    $month  = $adjusted_date['month'];
    $year   = $adjusted_date['year'];

    // Determine the total days in the month
    $total_days = $this->get_total_days($month, $year);

    // Set the starting day of the week
    $start_days = array('sunday' => 0, 'monday' => 1, 'tuesday' => 2, 'wednesday' => 3, 'thursday' => 4, 'friday' => 5, 'saturday' => 6);
    $start_day = ( ! isset($start_days[$this->start_day])) ? 0 : $start_days[$this->start_day];

    // Set the starting day number
    $local_date = mktime(12, 0, 0, $month, date('j'), $year);
    $date = getdate($local_date);
    $day  = $date["mday"];

    // Set the current month/year/day
    // We use this to determine the "today" date
    $cur_year   = date("Y", $this->local_time);
    $cur_month  = date("m", $this->local_time);
    $cur_day    = date("j", $this->local_time);

    $is_current_month = ($cur_year == $year AND $cur_month == $month) ? TRUE : FALSE;

    // Generate the template data array
    $this->parse_template();

    // Begin building the calendar output
    $out = $this->temp['table_open'];
    $out .= "\n";

    $out .= "\n";
    $out .= $this->temp['heading_row_start'];
    $out .= "\n";

    // "previous" month link
    if ($this->show_next_prev == TRUE)
    {
        // Add a trailing slash to the  URL if needed
        $this->next_prev_url = preg_replace("/(.+?)\/*$/", "\\1/",  $this->next_prev_url);

        $adjusted_date = $this->adjust_date($month - 1, $year);
        $out .= str_replace('{previous_url}', $this->next_prev_url.$adjusted_date['year'].'/'.$adjusted_date['month'], $this->temp['heading_previous_cell']);
        $out .= "\n";
    }

    // Heading containing the month/year
    $colspan = ($this->show_next_prev == TRUE) ? 5 : 7;

    $this->temp['heading_title_cell'] = str_replace('{colspan}', $colspan, $this->temp['heading_title_cell']);
    $this->temp['heading_title_cell'] = str_replace('{heading}', $this->get_month_name($month)."&nbsp;".$year, $this->temp['heading_title_cell']);

    $out .= $this->temp['heading_title_cell'];
    $out .= "\n";

    // "next" month link
    if ($this->show_next_prev == TRUE)
    {
        $adjusted_date = $this->adjust_date($month + 1, $year);
        $out .= str_replace('{next_url}', $this->next_prev_url.$adjusted_date['year'].'/'.$adjusted_date['month'], $this->temp['heading_next_cell']);
    }

    $out .= "\n";
    $out .= $this->temp['heading_row_end'];
    $out .= "\n";

    // Write the cells containing the days of the week
    $out .= "\n";
    $out .= $this->temp['week_row_start'];
    $out .= "\n";

    $day_names = $this->get_day_names();

    for ($i = 0; $i < 7; $i ++)
    {
        $out .= str_replace('{week_day}', $day_names[($start_day + $i) %7], $this->temp['week_day_cell']);
    }

    $out .= "\n";
    $out .= $this->temp['week_row_end'];
    $out .= "\n";

    // Build the main body of the calendar
    $limit = $day + 13;
    if ($limit > $total_days)
    {
        $total_days_left = $limit - $total_days;
    }
    while ($day <= $limit)
    {
        $out .= "\n";
        $out .= $this->temp['cal_row_start'];
        $out .= "\n";

        for ($i = 0; $i < 7; $i++)
        {
            if ($day > $total_days)
            {
                $day = 1;
                $limit = $total_days_left;
            }
            $out .= ($is_current_month == TRUE AND $day == $cur_day) ? $this->temp['cal_cell_start_today'] : $this->temp['cal_cell_start'];

            if ($day > 0 AND $day <= $limit)
            {
                if (isset($data[$day]))
                {
                    // Cells with content
                    $temp = ($is_current_month == TRUE AND $day == $cur_day) ? $this->temp['cal_cell_content_today'] : $this->temp['cal_cell_content'];
                    $out .= str_replace('{day}', $day, str_replace('{content}', $data[$day], $temp));
                }
                else
                {
                    // Cells with no content
                    $temp = ($is_current_month == TRUE AND $day == $cur_day) ? $this->temp['cal_cell_no_content_today'] : $this->temp['cal_cell_no_content'];
                    $out .= str_replace('{day}', $day, $temp);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // Blank cells
                $out .= $this->temp['cal_cell_blank'];
            }

            $out .= ($is_current_month == TRUE AND $day == $cur_day) ? $this->temp['cal_cell_end_today'] : $this->temp['cal_cell_end'];                 
            $day++;
        }
        $out .= "\n";
        $out .= $this->temp['cal_row_end'];
        $out .= "\n";
    }
    $out .= "\n";
    $out .= $this->temp['table_close'];

    return $out;
}
```

You can see the differences between this one and the original one here:
http://www.diffnow.com/?report=51mkw

This will shows 2 weeks from the current date. But when you call the calendar library you need to specify the `start_day` to the current day by using `date('l')` and `strtolower()` like:

```
$prefs = array (
    'start_day'    => strtolower(date('l')),
);
$this->load->library('calendar', $prefs);
```

Otherwise, the days would show up incorrectly.

Comment: How will I be able to navigate while viewing two weeks per month with the Codeigniter's calender `next_prev_url` configuration?

Comment: Oh, there's a problem too. The dates on `heading_title_cell` do not correspond to the number dates, they mismatch, for example it says Sunday on 13th, Monday on 14th, Tuesday on 15th, etc...

Comment: @lolwut I'm sorry but I'm not sure about the `next_prev_url` issue. As for the mismatch, simply use `strtolower()` on `date('l')` in the `$prefs` array.